# Why this Simple case of psr-4 not working with composer

Tags: php, package, composer-php, psr-4

I am trying to understand how psr-4 works using composer. These are the contents of my composer.json file

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vehicle\\Car\\":"src/"
        }
    }
}
```

The Folder Structure is given below (please note I am using windows 10, so directory name casing should not matter I think)
The  folder where I have created 'vendor' folder is inside D:\temp\composer_test

```
D:\
  temp\
  composer_test\
    test.php
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    vendor\
      vehicle\
        car\
          src\
            Tire.php
```

Contents of test.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$tire = new Vehicle\Car\Tire();
```

Contents of Tire.php

```
<?php
namespace Vehicle\Car;
class Tire {
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "initialize Tire\n";
    }
}
```

But when I run the code (snapshot below) . I see error

D:\temp\composer_test>php test.php

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Vehicle\Car\Tire' not found in D:\temp\composer_test\test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in D:\temp\composer_test\test.php on line 3

I Don't know what is wrong I am doing. Problem is when I install any other standard package I can use it successfully which seems like using the same format

Comment: Perhaps simply `src/`  ain't `vendor/...`  (all paths relative to dirname of `composer.json`)? Just don't put files into `vendor/`  while you meant `src/` ? But that's just a guess, so maybe share a bit more what you're trying to do here? Have you really put your source files into the `vendor` folder? Are you perhaps looking into using your own project as a dependency already while building? Can you elaborate what you're describing by using the word _simple_?

Comment: And please [edit] your question to include your code/commands and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see _[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500)_ and _[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)_ for why. For instructions on formatting see _[How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)_. - code blocks also work well for shell commands here.

Comment: @hakre I have edited the question. All I am trying to do is to understand how psr-4 really works. What is confusing for me is that if I install any other standard package, it works and seems that it follows the same steps and uses same directory structure. So what is different about my code

Comment: Your code is different in-so-far that it is the root package. All other dependencies are **not** the root package. And only those are inside `vendor`, yours is root, leading, therefore at the root, living there and `vendor` just a detail.

Comment: You should absolutely stick to casing - when your namespace is `Vehicle\Car`, the corresponding folder should not be named `vehicle\car`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your composer.json should be:

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vehicle\\":"src/vehicle/"
        }
    }
}
```

Your directory structure should be:

```
D:\
  temp\
  composer_test\
    test.php
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    src\
      vehicle\
        car\
            Tire.php
```

Make sure to run `composer dump-autoload` to re-general the autoload files.

Also your namespace does not make much sense, naming your namespace Vehicle would mean that you only have vehicles in your repo. Usually you would name your namespace based on your project name, could be your brand or your username, or something more generic such as `App`.

So this would make more sense:

```php
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\":"src/"
        }
    }
}
```

then you have:

```
D:\
  temp\
  composer_test\
    test.php
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    src\
      vehicle\
        car\
            Tire.php
      plane\
        ...
```

and test.php

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$tire = new App\Vehicle\Car\Tire();
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But one thing still confusing me that why standard package works using same directory structure. They all goes inside a vendor/ folder and have files inside src/ folder. what changes should I make to work it like a standard package???

Comment: You don't need to make any changes. When someone else includes your package it will automatically enter the vendor folder.